# error The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later

Tags: 9

The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.  My drupal version is 9.2.5. How to open dev mode

Comment: Honestly need a question and description here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show all error messages with backtrace information, update `<drupal_root>/sites/default/settings.php`. Change the following line to `verbose`

```
$config['system.logging']['error_level'] = 'verbose';
```

Remember to change it back for production.

Comment: Bug my drupal version is 9.2.5, this setting not working. why?

Comment: Do you also have a `<drupal_root>/sites/default/settings.local.php` file?  You might need to update this instead.

Comment: Oh, thanks, it work now

Comment: Glad you got it working! 